# C++: Best way to draw a Graphics* object inside another Graphics* object

Tags: c++, graphics, bitmap, gdi+

Since `Gdiplus::Graphics::DrawGraphics(Graphics*, x, y)` doesn't exist, what would be the best way of doing something like this?

For instance, creating one Graphics object, using one or more of the various DrawXXX() methods, and then drawing the contents of that graphics bitmap to another graphics object?

Would this have to do with the associated `HBITMAP` object that is drawn to by the graphics object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the wrong mental image of a Graphics object.  It doesn't *contain* any graphics, it merely has *methods* that can draw graphics.  The only context it keeps is *where* the graphics are drawn.  To a bitmap, the screen, the printer, depending how the object was created.  The exact equivalent in the native winapi is a device context, a HDC.

Use a Bitmap or a GraphicsPath instead.  Or a function pointer to a drawing function.